# How do I return the current parse.com session token

Tags: parse-platform

In IOS, How do I return the current user's parse session token?

Once logged in, I want to return what my current session token is.

```
NSString *token = [PFUser currentUser] sessionToken;
```

Comment: I am having trouble finding the api that shows where I can return current session once logged in...I tried [PFSession currentSession] out of pure instinct but it wasnt right

Comment: and per the API, it says [PFUser sessionToken], but that didnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *token = [PFUser currentUser].sessionToken;
```

**Swift**

```
let token = PFUser.current().sessionToken
```